# Relation between residuals of lognormal and gamma, insurance fit

Tags: r, math

I am trying to make a model fit with glm in Rstudio. I first tried with the Gamma distribution, but the fit was poor.

[image: See here]

Then I accidently tried to fit

```
glm(log(X) ~ age+insurance_sum+excess+segment, family=Gamma(link="log"),data=insurance_data)
```

Looking at the residuals, I noticed the lookalike to when I fitted the lognormal with the GAMLSS package

```
gamlss( X~age+insurance_sum+excess+segment, family= LOGNO(), data=insurance_data)
```

Can anyone explain to me the relation?

Comment: The residuals were almost unique, apart from the scaling of the Y-axis

Comment: What exactly does 'the residuals were almost unique' mean?  Please provide the output that you are using to make your assessment.  Also note that the gamma and lognormal distributions are both right skewed and can look fairly similar so it wouldn't surprise me if you got similar results.

Comment: I've added a photo. Didn't know it was so easy.
I don't think I've ever stumbled across the log(X) ~Gamma. Here you can see the density
http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GammaLoggamma.pdf

Note also, that when I use X ~Gamma, also with log link, I am getting a poor fit.

Comment: This is a conceptual discussion question, so it's more on-topic for stats.stackexchange.com.